# Android: How to create WebView like YouTube has in his app

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, youtube, android-webview

**YouTube app:** In about tab of any channel, there are some few Social Networking website links of the channel. I visited some of the links and checked that links open in WebView. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The WebView seems different from normal WebView. Its contain address bar and overflow menu like Chrome.

1. Are they added `EditText` for address bar and `Overflow menu` in `WebView` activity?
2. Are they using any library because it's also written `Powered by Chrome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They use Chrome Custom Tabs

> **What are Chrome Custom Tabs?**
>
> App developers face a choice when a user taps a URL to either launch a
>   browser, or build their own in-app browser using WebViews.
>
> Both options present challenges — launching the browser is a heavy
>   context switch that isn't customizable, while WebViews don't share
>   state with the browser and add maintenance overhead.
>
> Chrome Custom Tabs give apps more control over their web experience,
>   and make transitions between native and web content more seamless
>   without having to resort to a WebView.
>
> Chrome Custom Tabs allow an app to customize how Chrome looks and
>   feels. An app can change things like:
>
> - Toolbar color
> - Enter and exit animations
> - Add custom actions to the Chrome toolbar, overflow menu and bottom toolbar

It's available in support library :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'
}
```

Usage :

```
String url = ¨https://google.com/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Check more info [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Answer (score 0):

it wont be difficult to make it yourself with the functionalities that had but i believe that the webview is based on Chromium  ([WebView Chromium](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview))

and as you know chrome is token from chromium project